# GET-запрос на Python

Tags: python, url, get, синтаксический-анализ

Подскажите, товарищи, почему, казалось бы, одинаковые фрагменты кода ведут себя по-разному. На сайте yandex открывается и сохраняется в файл искомая страница, а на сайте moyareklama - главная?

```
import urllib

base = "http://www.moyareklama.ru/single_ad_new.php?"
data = {"id":"201623465"}
url = base + urllib.urlencode(data)
print url
page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
f = open ("1.html", "w")
f.write(page)
f.close()
print page

##base = "http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?"
##data = (("text","python"),("lr","192"))
##url = base + urllib.urlencode(data)
##print url
##page = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
##f = open ("1.html", "w")
##f.write(page)
##f.close()
##print page
```

С cookie тоже не работает...

```
import requests 
url = "http://www.moyareklama.ru/" 
r = requests.get(url) 
cookies = r.cookies payload = {"id":"201686924"} 
url = "http://www.moyareklama.ru/single_ad_new.php" 
s = requests.get(url, params = payload, cookies = cookies)

print cookies 
print s.url
##print s.text
```

Comment: вопрос решил

Comment: Тогда расскажи как и закрывай вопрос=)

Comment: Вы были правы насчёт cookies, но их нужно забирать не с главной страницы, а со страницы с названием города (http://www.moyareklama.ru/Брянск/), поскольку в cookies передаётся параметр, содержащий индекс города. После этого всё начинает работать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он пустит вас туда только если у вас есть куки, примите их сначала а потом сможете отдав их этой странице в запросе получить ее

Comment: с cookie тоже не работает..

Answer (score 2):

Так уж устроен этот ресурс. Попробуй через браузер или курлом. Он всегда возвращает в начале главную. Подозреваю, ему сначала сессия нужна.